# Cloudant/CouchDB triggers an event by deleting a document

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I am trying "update handlers" to catch create/update/delete events in IBM cloudant. It works when a document is created or updated, but not deleted. Is there any other way I can catch an event that a document is deleted and then create a document in another database to record this event? Thank you.

Comment: Could you be more explicit about what you want to trigger with "delete" events? Does it modify CouchDB's data? Is it a long process or not?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to monitor a couchDB/Cloudant database for changes take a look at the `/_changes` feed: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.0.0/api/database/changes.html. You could implement an app that continuously monitors the feed and "logs" the desired information whenever a document is inserted, updated or deleted. For some programming languages there are libraries (such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/follow for Node.js) that make it easy to manage/process the feed.